# action not found - route correct - view rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

my rails app is calling a method which doesnt exist.

The route for my called method is:

> get_json GET    /get_json(.:format)         data#get_json

my Controller code:

```
class DataController < ApplicationController


 before_filter :authenticate
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

protected
  def authenticate
    token = params[:token]
    @user = User.find_by(token: token)
    if @user.nil?
      render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized
      return
    end
  end



  def get_json
    @users = User.all
    @owners = Owner.all
    @tags=Tag.all
    @ideas=Idea.all
    @votes=Vote.all
    @votings=Voting.all
  end
end
```

If i do a get request on this. I get an empty Json String:

```
{"tags":[],"ideas":[],"owners":[],"votes":[],"votings":[],"users":[]}
```

And here's my data view (getjson.json.jbuilder):

```
    json.tags @tags do |tag|
  json.extract! tag, :id, :typ, :text
end

json.ideas @ideas do |idea|
  json.extract! idea, :id, :title, :text, :owner_id, :voting_id, :voteCount
  json.tags idea.tags do |tag|
    json.extract! tag, :id
  end
end

json.owners @owners do |owner|
  json.extract! owner, :id, :name, :user_id
end

json.votes @votes do |vote|
  json.extract! vote, :id, :kommentar, :owner_id, :voting_id, :idea_id
end

json.votings @votings do |voting|
  json.extract! voting, :id, :status
end

json.users @users do |user|
  json.extract! user, :id, :name, :token, :owner_id, :isLoggedIn
end
```

WE have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Look in your route `data#getjson` but you have `get_json` method in the controller not `getjson`.

Comment: Thats just a typo..
i found the solution. keyword : protected
i should have wrote it at the bottom, not top.
thats why rails can't find the other action and just thinks.. ok.. no action? but the view is here? lets just render the view..

:)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put protected on top of your Controller.
Everything beyond it is protected. That's why it couldn't find the action.

like this:

```
    class DataController < ApplicationController

     before_filter :authenticate
      skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

     def get_json
        @users = User.all
        @owners = Owner.all
        @tags=Tag.all
        @ideas=Idea.all
        @votes=Vote.all
        @votings=Voting.all
      end

    protected
      def authenticate
        token = params[:token]
        @user = User.find_by(token: token)
        if @user.nil?
          render nothing: true, status: :unauthorized
          return
        end
      end
    end
```